# How to invoke a groovy file ( filename.groovy ) or groovy script via shell script?

Tags: shell, groovy

Same groovy file can be invoked by .bat file as :

java -cp lib/groovy-all-2.4.6.jar;lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar;. groovy.ui.GroovyMain PostBuild.groovy

Need to perform same operation but via Shell Script or any.sh file on Linux

Comment: Use `:` to separate the paths in the cp.  Otherwise it's the same on unix

Comment: Following error is coming :Error: Could not find or load main class groovy.ui.GroovyMain

Comment: Then your classpath is not setup properly

Comment: Need your help. Please tell me what details are needed from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Could not find or load main class groovy.ui.GroovyMain" : This indicates that java was launched but groovy-all-2.4.6.jar was not found from classpath.

Here's a couple hints:

- Check that you replaced semicolon  `;`  with colon `:` in your -cp parameter.
- When you give `lib/groovy-all-2.4.6.jar` in your -cp parameter, java
  assumes the lib directory (with groovy jar) exists in current
  directory. Note that current directory is not (necessarily) the
  directory where the shell script is, but it's the directory where you
  are when you launch that script (unless you explicitly change current
  dir within the script).
- Check that groovy-all-2.4.6.jar exists in lib subdirectory under
  current directory and the script executing user has read rights in
  that directory and jar files.